# What happens in Android if you run code that requires a permission but fail to have it?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am talking about the quality issue (bug) that an Android app needs a permission that is declared in the Manifest, but fails to request it from the user at the appropriate time and executes the code without the necessary permission. This was not possible in older Android versions (user accepts all permissions in bulk), but seems to be possible when using newer versions that copy Apple in most regards.

At least during testing one can start background services and use bluetooth without any alert by Google popping up. Is that different for apps in production?

1. Does the app crash with an Exception?
2. Does the code get executed?
3. Does the app get rejected in review? (Always?)
4. Does the app get delisted from the store?
5. Does it depend on Android's Version?

I deal with an age old app that has bluetooth discovery code to find and connect to dedicated hardware, that is rarely used via a cordova plugin triggered by content. There is old altbeacon code potentially activated that may even need access background location (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Permissions). It will take some time to get this dead code up to quality. Definitely more time than the week we have.

Comment: If you executes the code without the necessary permission . It will throw an Exception . Rest questions r base less because u certainly do not want to create a App which crash if permission is not allowed . for 5th one Runtime permission starts from android 6 which is a long way down.

Comment: you should be able to test this yourself, just write something which requires a permission without having requested it

Comment: My update to the question should answer some of your objections. A crash would be ok for now and would only trigger in extremely rare conditions when testing content. But right now there is no time to fix it properly and it does not affect user experience.

Comment: I tested it and the bluetooth discovery code executes and connects via UART without crash and alert. That's why I ask. I can even start altbeacon background services without crash and permission in the manifest. It just works.

Answer (score 1):

Does the app crash with an Exception?
yes if you try to have operations depends on returned date witch is null

Does the code get executed?
code will execute with exceptions because data access denied you can check if permission granted or not and add scenario for each state

Does the app get rejected in review? (Always?) not sure but with crashes there is high potential to get rejected

Does the app get delisted from the store?
depends on why and how you are using data
Does it depend on Android's Version?
yes access data and permissions changing point is android oreo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope in release the exceptions get thrown. In testing they didn't. The user cannot trigger the exception. Only location based content that uses beacon functions can trigger it. The code was tested and did not crash and noone noticed the missing grant-permission call until today. A crash during testing would have been helpful.

Comment: add crashlatycs  or any crash reporter to your project to collect any error

Answer (score 0):

My tests with Bluetooth permissions revealed the following: Required permissions are BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, BLUETOOTH and for VERSION_CODES.Q additionally Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION (see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Permissions).

BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, BLUETOOTH do not show any system alert-dialogue to the user. In Android Q+ if you fail to check for the **required** ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, nothing happens and your code executes without exception (mine did execute an UART command on hardware with Samsung tablet). The app passed review although the check is missing (of course I will fix that ASAP).

Note: the doc is ambiguous and states: "**Services running on Android 10 and higher cannot discover Bluetooth devices unless they have the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** permission." Probably general scanning while the app is active could be allowed. In that case missing exception would be explained.